# Pyodbc rollback() proper use

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I have a question about the rollback feature of pyodbc and how I was planning on using it.

I am interacting with a SQL server and executing a list of stored procedures.  But I want to try and wrap these stored procedures into a try/except to "rollback" the changes. Right now, if one of the stored procedure fails, then as long as I quit my python program, everything is reverted back.  But I want to "revert back" without forcing the app to close, like shown below.

```
try:
    cursor.execute('exec storedproc1')
    cursor.execute('exec storedproc2')
    cursor.execute('exec storedproc3')
    cursor.execute('exec storedproc4')
    
    connection.commit()
except:
    connection.rollback()
```

Is the above code using the rollback feature appropriately?  Will the above code have the same results as closing the app if any of the executes fail and the connection.commit() is never called?

Thanks

Comment: I think you want to loop over the procedures, and wrap each call in a `try / except`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Ok, so each stored procedure needs to have a try / except with a rollback after it?  The problem is I need to rollback all 4 execute statements if say # 4 fails.

Comment: Then what's wrong with the current code?  The transaction will roll back and the app can continue?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I was not sure if what I wrote WOULD do what i was asking. I have never had to use the rollback feature, because I've always just closed the app, but now I am giving the app to someone else to use so I want it to work better and not for them to quit the app and re-open it.

Comment: Then you need to test your code.  Random people on the internet can't be sure that it meets all your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe you are doing it correctly.

The routine below is some code I used to read a list of sql files (`migration_files`) and execute them all in one transaction.  You can do something similar and loop over the SP calls.

```
def run_migration(migration_files):
    conn = init_pyodbc_connection(autocommit=False)
    conn.autocommit = False
    cur = conn.cursor()
    for migration_file in migration_files:
        with open(migration_file.strip()) as fh:
            migrate_sql = fh.read()
        try:
            cur.execute(migrate_sql)
        except:
            conn.rollback()
            raise
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```